# Volley is not working when I switch my network from one wifi(W1) to other wifi(W2)

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley

I use volley on the android application to connect remote server, when the remote server and smartphone is in same internet environment(same wifi), it works fine, But when I switch smartphone into another wifi(at this time,server and smartphone has separate internet environment), the volley cannot connect to remote server, How should I handle it

I tired to add user permission on internet, it still doesn't work

This is my code for sending beacon information to remote server

```
private void SendBeaconToServer(String url, final Blesave BLE){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("Beacon回应是", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Beacon错误", error.toString());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("timestamp", String.valueOf(BLE.getTimestamp()));
                params.put("uuid", String.valueOf(BLE.getUuid()));
                params.put("major", String.valueOf(BLE.getMajor()));
                params.put("minor1", String.valueOf(BLE.getMinor1()));
                params.put("rssi1", String.valueOf(BLE.getRssi1()));
                params.put("minor2", String.valueOf(BLE.getMinor2()));
                params.put("rssi2", String.valueOf(BLE.getRssi2()));
                params.put("minor3", String.valueOf(BLE.getMinor3()));
                params.put("rssi3", String.valueOf(BLE.getRssi3()));
                params.put("people", worker_id);
                params.put("department", worker_department);
                return params;
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

I hope the smartphone could upload data to remote server even server and smartphone is in different wifi environment

Comment: what is your url? is it local or remote server?

Comment: If Server is connected locally only, then your mobile should be in same network.

Comment: I put my php file on the wampserver localserver, the url looks like this `private String beacon_URL = "http://192.168.*.**/volley/Beacon_upload.php";` , I think I found the problems, thanks very much for your reminds, Do you have any recommendation of remote server with MYSQL database, Thanks for your reply

Comment: @bricker, use public ip instead of private one. thank u